# execute sudo script on linux from windows

Tags: linux, windows, sudo, plink

I need to connect to linux,run script which requires sudo.

now i am trying this way:

```
plink.exe -ssh -pw mypassword -noagent myname@10.111.11.123 "sudo /var/squid/myscript.sh
```

in linux i added in /etc/sudoers file:

```
 myname  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/squid/myscript.sh
```

and

```
chown u+x /var/squid/myscript.sh
```

the script inside:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch testfile.txt
```

When i run the script from linux console:

```
sudo /var/squid/myscript.sh
```

it works with no password, but when i try to do it from remote windows using plink.exe it does not work. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you happen to have the `requiretty` set in you sudoers file?  https://www.google.com/search?q=plink+tty+sudo

Comment: i dont have it in sudoers

Answer (score 4):

Ok,
everything works fine - had to add -t in plink so now it should be:

```
plink.exe -ssh -pw mypassword -t myname@10.111.11.123 "sudo /var/squid/myscript.sh"
```

Thanks for help